# How can I handle a d3.js parse error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, d3.js

I wrote a little function plotter that animates parametric curves based on user input. However, it's possible to enter values that result in +-infinity, or NaN. In this situation d3 throws a parse error.

Is there a way to "catch" this error, so to speak, and display a message to the user? Surrounding my function in a try/catch doesn't work, as it's not really an exception, it just can't draw the path - hence the parse error.

I would like to be able to display a message to the user when that happens.

http://candpgeneration.com/toys/d3/plotter5.html

All the JS is in the source. If you enter something like x = 10/t, it will try to divide by 0, and the following error can be seen in the console: "Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN... "

Answer (score 0):

You could try evaluating the user-submitted expressions with a test value and catching the possible exception before drawing the graphs. For evaluating, you might want to use an external library like [this](http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/), since the native `eval()` function has security issues.

Comment: I'm already evaluating the expressions. I was hoping to avoid checking for NaN or infinity at every computation, since there could be thousands of numbers to check. But I will try it, and see if it slows things down.